# How to randomly place elements on a web page

Tags: html, css

I need to make an art gallery for my website and I want to take an asymmetric approach by placing the artwork and descriptions randomly across the page with no symmetry. It should look a bit like this, with the colored squares being the divs containing each image and description:

[image]

Keep in mind that I also want to include text in each div, so it's not just the images. The max-width of my container is 1504 pixels. Resizing isn't necessary because I have the min-width set to 1504 as well. I don't know much about CSS or HTML as I'm doing this for a school thing.  How do I go about making this?

Comment: Are you wanting the layout to be completely random or more of a [masonry layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)?

Comment: Also, do you want to place them automatically, or do you mind manually coding their positions?

Comment: @Jacob Lockard I don't mind manually coding them. I want them to be completely randomly placed so that nothing lines up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind manually coding the positions, you can simply use absolute [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Essentially, you'll need to:

1. Give your container (which might just be the `body`) a constant width and height. I arbitrarily chose 400x400 in the example.
2. Add `position: relative` to your container to allow the content boxes to be positioned relative to the container. This is not necessary if your container is the `body`.
3. Add `position: absolute` to all your content boxes (the `.box` elements in my example).
4. Use the [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top), [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom), [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), and/or [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) properties to position your content boxes as desired.

Here's a (miniature) example:

```css
.container {
  /* You can set this to whatever you wish. */
  width: 400px;
  
  /* You'll need to set a height. */
  height: 400px;
  
  /* Allows positioning relative to this container. */
  position: relative;
  
  /* For clarity. */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
}

.box#one {
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  
  top: 20px;
  left: 60px;
}

.box#two {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  
  top: 50px;
  right: 100px;
}

.box#three {
  width: 67px;
  height: 76px;
  background: purple;
  
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 278px;
}

.box#four {
  width: 150px;
  height: 160px;
  background: yellow;
  
  top: 203px;
  left: 100px;
}

.box#five {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  
  top: 110px;
  left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="one">
    <!-- You can put your content in here. -->
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two">
    <!-- You can put your content in here. -->
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="three">
    <!-- You can put your content in here. -->
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="four">
    <!-- You can put your content in here. -->
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="five">
    <!-- You can put your content in here. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! I tried it with my webpage and it worked perfectly. I wasn't really familiar with the position property which is why I struggled initially. I've only learned some of the basics for school. Thanks!